# Why is the font quality of JQuery fadeIn() worse on Internet Explorer than Firefox/Chrome?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, fadein

Why is the **quality** of this fadeIn/fadeOut demo much **smoother** when viewed in Firefox/Chrome than when viewed in IE8?

http://tanguay.info/web/examples/jquerflash2

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer's legacy/proprietary DirectX opacity filters disable ClearType when you use them (because otherwise the text is completely corrupted). IE8 and below do not support CSS opacity, and hence there's no solid workaround. Typically, for IE, you'll want to remove the Filter when rendering the text for reading so that ClearType works properly.